# Terraform Lambda in VPC (Peered with MongoDB Atlas) Connection NAT Gateway

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws, mongodb-atlas, aws-secrets-manager

I have built out a Terraform config that deploys a MongoDB atlas cloud cluster, and sets up a VPC peer with my AWS account. The terraform configuration stores the credentials in AWS Secrets Manager. Unfortunately, my Lambda is unable to access the Secrets Manager API endpoint or the MongoDB cluster hosted on Atlas. I have read that I need to set up a NAT gateway on my VPC to access the public internet. I am not a networking pro, and I have tried adding a bunch of different configurations to no avail. Please help:

1. Do I need to set up a NAT gateway for my VPC to access Secrets
   Manager? Or can I just host the Secret in the VPC somehow? What is
   best practice here?
2. Do I need to set up a NAT gateway for my Lambda
   to access my Atlas hosted MongoDB cluster, even though they are on
   the same VPC and I have whitelisted the security group my Lambda is in?
3. How do I set up a NAT Gateway to allow my Lambda to connect to my
   Atlas Cluster in Terraform?

Ideally I would like to lockdown the connection to the outside internet as much as possible, but if that's not an option, I am fine with any implementation that just works.

Here is my Terraform config

```
variable "admin_profile" {
  type = string
  default = "superadmin"
}


variable "region" {
  type    = string
  default = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = var.admin_profile
  region  = "us-west-2"
  alias   = "admin"
}


// create mongo db organization + cluster on atlas

provider "mongodbatlas" {
  public_key  = var.atlas_public_key
  private_key = var.atlas_private_key
}

//superadmin creds
variable aws_account_id {
  type = string
}

variable atlas_private_key {
  type = string
}

variable atlas_public_key {
  type = string
}

variable atlas_region {
  type    = string
  default = "US_WEST_2"
}

variable atlas_org_id {
  type    = string
  default = "" #EXCLUDE THIS
}


// generated creds for db
variable atlas_db_user {
  default = "mongo_user"
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
  #override_special = "_%-"
}

locals {
  atlas_db_password = random_password.password.result
}

variable atlas_db_vpc_cidr {
  default = "192.168.224.0/21"
}

// resources
resource "mongodbatlas_project" "cluster-partner-project" {
  name   = "live"
  org_id = var.atlas_org_id
}

resource "mongodbatlas_cluster" "cluster-partner" {
  project_id                   = mongodbatlas_project.cluster-partner-project.id
  name                         = "cluster-partner"
  num_shards                   = 1
  replication_factor           = 3
  provider_backup_enabled      = true
  cluster_type                 = "REPLICASET"
  auto_scaling_disk_gb_enabled = true
  mongo_db_major_version       = "4.2"

  //Provider Settings "block"
  provider_name               = "AWS"
  disk_size_gb                = 40
  provider_disk_iops          = 120
  provider_volume_type        = "STANDARD"
  provider_encrypt_ebs_volume = true
  provider_instance_size_name = "M10"
  provider_region_name        = var.atlas_region
}

resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "cluster-partner-user" {
  username           = var.atlas_db_user
  password           = local.atlas_db_password
  auth_database_name = "admin"
  project_id         = mongodbatlas_project.cluster-partner-project.id
  roles {
    role_name     = "readAnyDatabase"
    database_name = "admin"
  }

  roles {
    role_name     = "readWrite"
    database_name = "app_db"
  }
}

resource "mongodbatlas_network_container" "cluster-partner-network" {
  atlas_cidr_block = var.atlas_db_vpc_cidr
  project_id       = mongodbatlas_project.cluster-partner-project.id
  provider_name    = "AWS"
  region_name      = var.atlas_region
}

resource "mongodbatlas_network_peering" "cluster-partner-network-peering" {
  accepter_region_name   = var.region
  project_id             = mongodbatlas_project.cluster-partner-project.id
  container_id           = mongodbatlas_network_container.cluster-partner-network.container_id
  provider_name          = "AWS"
  route_table_cidr_block = aws_vpc.primary.cidr_block
  vpc_id                 = aws_vpc.primary.id
  aws_account_id         = var.aws_account_id
}

resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_whitelist" "default-db-access" {
  project_id         = mongodbatlas_project.cluster-partner-project.id
  aws_security_group = aws_security_group.primary_default.id
  comment            = "Access for App to MongoDB"
  depends_on         = [mongodbatlas_network_peering.cluster-partner-network-peering]
}

// create a vpc in AWS
resource "aws_vpc" "primary" {
  provider             = aws.admin
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
}
// Internet Gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "primary" {
  provider = aws.admin
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.primary.id
}
// route table
resource "aws_route" "primary-internet_access" {
  provider               = aws.admin
  route_table_id         = aws_vpc.primary.main_route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  gateway_id             = aws_internet_gateway.primary.id
}

resource "aws_route" "peeraccess" {
  provider                  = aws.admin
  route_table_id            = aws_vpc.primary.main_route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block    = var.atlas_db_vpc_cidr
  vpc_peering_connection_id = mongodbatlas_network_peering.cluster-partner-network-peering.connection_id
  depends_on                = [aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter.peer]
}

//subnets

//public
resource "aws_subnet" "primary-az1" {
  provider                = aws.admin
  tags = {
    Name = "public primary subnet"
  }
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.primary.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone       = "${var.region}a"
}

//private
resource "aws_subnet" "primary-az2" {
  provider                = aws.admin
  tags = {
    Name = "private subnet 0"
  }
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.primary.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.2.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  availability_zone       = "${var.region}b"
}

// security groups for mongo vpc connect

resource "aws_security_group" "primary_default" {
  provider    = aws.admin
  name_prefix = "defaultvpc-"
  description = "Default security group for all instances in VPC ${aws_vpc.primary.id}"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.primary.id
  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [
      aws_vpc.primary.cidr_block,
      var.atlas_db_vpc_cidr
    ]
    # cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

// vpc peering auto accept

resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" "peer" {
  provider                  = aws.admin
  vpc_peering_connection_id = mongodbatlas_network_peering.cluster-partner-network-peering.connection_id
  auto_accept               = true
}

// save mongo account details to secret manager


resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "partner_iam_mongo_access" {
  provider = aws.admin
  name     = "mongo-access"
}

locals {
  mongo_credentials = {
    connection_strings = mongodbatlas_cluster.cluster-partner.connection_strings
    password           = local.atlas_db_password
  }
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "partner_iam_mongo_access" {
  provider      = aws.admin
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.partner_iam_mongo_access.id
  secret_string = jsonencode(local.mongo_credentials)
}


// create lambdas for each of the key steps in the app

// have to add the vpc

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  provider = aws.admin
  name     = "lambda_policy"
  role     = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id
  policy   = file("./lambda-policy.json")
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "aws_lambda_vpc_access_execution_role" {
  provider = aws.admin
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  provider           = aws.admin
  name               = "lambda-vpc-role-managed"
  assume_role_policy = file("./lambda-assume-policy.json")
}

data "archive_file" "test-connection" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "./test-connection"
  output_path = "./test-connection_deploy.zip"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "test-connection" {
  provider         = aws.admin
  filename         = "./test-connection_deploy.zip"
  function_name    = "test-connection"
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "test-connection"
  runtime          = "go1.x"
  timeout          = 15
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.test-connection.output_base64sha256
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [aws_subnet.primary-az1.id] // public subnet
    security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.primary_default.id]
  }

}
```

Here are my tfvars

```
admin_profile     = "default"
atlas_private_key = 
atlas_public_key  = 
atlas_org_id      = 
aws_account_id    =
```

Here is my Lambda policy (lambda-policy.json)

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
            "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
            "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds",
            "secretsmanager:ListSecrets"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is my Lambda policy (lambda-assume-policy.json)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com", "ec2.amazonaws.com"]
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the (GoLang) code for my Lambda

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "errors"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/sparrc/go-ping"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/secretsmanager"  
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)


type MongoCreds struct {
    ConnectionStrings []map[string]interface{} `json:"connection_strings"`
    Password          string   `json:"password"`
}

var MainRegion = "us-west-2"

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, updatedValues interface{}) (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("we are pinging")
    pinger, err := ping.NewPinger("www.google.com")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pinger.Count = 3
    pinger.Run() // blocks until finished
    stats := pinger.Statistics() // get send/receive/rtt stats
    fmt.Println(stats)
    fmt.Println("connecting to mongo")
    err = ConnectToMongoClient()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failure to connect to mongo")
    }
    return "", err
}

func ConnectToMongoClient() error {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(MainRegion),
    }))

    svc := secretsmanager.New(sess)
    input := &secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId: aws.String("mongo-access"),
    }
    fmt.Println("getting credentials")

    secret, err := svc.GetSecretValue(input)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var mongo_creds MongoCreds
    secretJson := []byte(*secret.SecretString)
    err = json.Unmarshal(secretJson, &mongo_creds)
    fmt.Println("credentials fetched")
    fmt.Println(mongo_creds)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var mongoURI string 
    for _, connection := range(mongo_creds.ConnectionStrings) {
        if val, ok := connection["standard_srv"]; ok {
            mongoURI = val.(string)
        }
    }
    if mongoURI == "" {
        return errors.New("Unable to parse a connecting string from secret")
    }
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURI).SetAuth(options.Credential{Username: "mongo_user", Password: mongo_creds.Password})
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    fmt.Println("connecting")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return err
    }

    ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    if err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary()); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return err
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

If anyone can recommend an implementation or adjustment to my VPC configuration or my Lambda code that would allow access to the Secrets Manager and my Mongo Cluster. Ideally, keeping all traffic in the VPC, but if public internet access is necessary, so be it.

**Edit** The error I am getting is a Timeout. Note, even if I hardcode the credentials (and skip the Secret Manager step),  I am still timing out when attempting to connect to the Atlas hosted Mongo instance.

Answer (score 5):

> Do I need to set up a NAT gateway for my VPC to access Secrets
> Manager? Or can I just host the Secret in the VPC somehow?

You either need to create a NAT gateway, or configure a [VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoint-overview.html) for Secrets Manager.

> What is best practice here?

[Create a VPC endpoint](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/vpc_endpoint) for Secrets Manager.

> Do I need to set up a NAT gateway for my Lambda to access my Atlas
> hosted MongoDB cluster, even though they are on the same VPC and I
> have whitelisted the security group my Lambda is in?

No, the whole point of the VPC peering is that you can connect directly within your VPC, without going out over the Internet. Note that they are not "in the same VPC" but are in two separate VPCs with a peering connection.

I don't see any issues in your Terraform, it appears to me that the Lambda function should be able to connect to the Mongo Atlas cluster. It may help if you add the actual error message you are seeing when it can't connect to your original question.

The Terraform code would look like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "secretsmanager" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name      = "com.amazonaws.us-west-2.secretsmanager"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"

  security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.sg1.id,
  ]

  private_dns_enabled = true
}
```

Comment: even when I override the secretmanager request, and manually hardcode the credentials, I get a timeout when pinging Atlas. The error is a timeout.

Comment: Sorry I have to downvote you. There is no documented support for VPC endpoints for Secrets Manager in Terraform.

Comment: @XaxD that seems unnecessary. I linked you to the documentation. I just added the Terraform example to my answer. I'm not sure why you say there is no documented support for this. Terraform supports all AWS VPC endpoint types, you simply have to specify the AWS service name when you configure the `vpc_endpoint` resource.

Comment: com.amazonaws.us-west-2.secretsmanager is not supported

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: InvalidParameter: Endpoint type (Gateway) does not match available service types ([Interface]).

Comment: @XaxD and you have `vpc_endpoint_type` set to `Interface`? Perhaps you should include the Terraform code that is resulting in that error.

Comment: Actually, I added your suggested code. I'm now getting ` Error creating VPC Endpoint: InvalidVpcId.NotFound: The Vpc Id vpc-xxxxx does not exist` (but it does -- I see it in the console)

Comment: I'm almost there. just have to figure out how to get the new VPC endpoint

Comment: I am now getting `RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://secretsmanager.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/\": dial tcp: lookup secretsmanager.us-west-2.amazonaws.com on 169.254.78.1:53: no such host`

Comment: What is the code that is getting that error? Where is that code running?

Comment: it's included in the question ^^ the golang code calls `input := &secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId: aws.String("mongo-access"),
    }`

Comment: `no such host` seems weird, but I think it may be a security group issue. Did you set the rules on the security group assigned to the VPC endpoint to allow access from your Lambda function?

Comment: they are in the same security group defined in the TF `aws_security_group.primary_default.id`